# Subharmonic function bounded on boundary of domain

Tags: complex-analysis

I am dealing with perron method and have some problem with proving the following lemma:

Suppose $\Omega$ is a **bounded**, domain in $\mathbb{C}$ and $u \in \mathcal{SH}(\Omega) \cap\mathcal{C}(\Omega)$ is such that $\overline{lim}_{\Omega \ni z \rightarrow z_0}u(z) < M$ for all $z_0 \in \partial\Omega$. Prove that $u<M$ in $\Omega$.

It is easy to show (reasoning by contradiction) from maximum principle that if $u<M$ is not true in $\Omega$ then arbitrarily close to the boundary one can find a point $z$ with $u(z)\ge M$ yet I have a problem with showing that some points will actually converge to some $z_0$ from boundary.

Comment: It's not true for unbounded $\Omega.$

Comment: Is there an easy counterexample in that setting ?

Comment: $u(z) = \operatorname{Re} \exp (e^z)$ on $\Omega = \{ z : \lvert \operatorname{Im} z\rvert < \pi/2\}$. Since $\lvert \exp (e^z)\rvert = 1$ on $\partial \Omega$, it follows that $\lvert u(z)\rvert \leqslant 1 < 2$ there. But $u$ is unbounded on the real axis.

Comment: Also consider $u(x+iy) = y$ on the upper half plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\partial \Omega$ is compact for bounded $\Omega$.

For every $z_0 \in \partial \Omega$, there is an $\varepsilon(z_0) > 0$ and a $\delta(z_0) > 0$ such that $u(z) < M - \varepsilon(z_0)$ for all $z \in \Omega \cap B_{\delta(z_0)}(z_0)$. Cover $\partial \Omega$ by finitely many disks $B_{\delta(z_k)}(z_k)$, $1 \leqslant k \leqslant m$, then with

$$\varepsilon = \min \{\varepsilon(z_k) : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant m\}$$

we have $u(z) < M-\varepsilon$ for all $z \in \Omega \cap U$, where

$$U = \bigcup_{k = 1}^m B_{\delta(z_k)}(z_k).$$